# android sqlite 'like' query and modulo expression

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

when i use LIKE query in android sql, i want 'contains' query about some input.

```
db.query(TABLE,
         new String[]{COLUMN},
         CONDITIONS + " LIKE " + "?",
         new String[]{("%" + input + "%")},
         null
         null
         ORDER_COLUMN + " DESC",
         null);
```

query is working well, but when i use '%' character in input, it working like empty string.

i want use '%' character which like normal string.

how can i do..?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`LIKE y ESCAPE z`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) form to specify an escape character for the LIKE expression, and then use that escape character to prefix any `%` in your LIKE expression that needs to be taken literally. For example:

```
sqlite> create table t(a);
sqlite> insert into t values('a%b');
sqlite> insert into t values('ab');
sqlite> insert into t values('aa%bb');
sqlite> select * from t where a like '%a\%b%' escape '\';
a%b
aa%bb
```

Comment: thank you.
but that means any one character is need for escape?
i want search all character use like query.

Comment: Yes you need to select a character for that purpose.

Comment: oh i see.
have a nice day :)